# Imported .obj Head Model missing faces

Tags: import, faces, obj

I have a problem with my head model. I used Mixamo Fuse to create only the head. I exported the head in Obj. format. On importing it to Blender, the model looks like this. Does anyone know why there are some missing faces? How to fix this problem quickly, as well as prevent the similar issues? Thank you guys.
[image]

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: idk why there are missing faces, but if that's symmetrical, delete the right (model left) half and use a mirror modifier.